# Convert multi-level UL to selectbox with optgroups using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I need to take a multi-level ul and create a select box with optgroups. I'd like to do this with jQuery. The optgroup labels would be the parents of any children.

**My markup:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Section 1</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Section 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Section 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Section 2.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Section 2.3</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Section 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**What I need:**

```
<select>
<option value="#">Section 1</option>
<optgroup label="Section 2">
    <option value="#">Section 2.1</option>
    <option value="#">Section 2.3</option>
    <option value="#">Section 2.3</option>
</optgroup>
<option value="#">Section 3</option>
</select>
```

So far, I can create a select box but it only respects one level:
**http://jsfiddle.net/RyanBrackett/0wp0ypng/**

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is your requirement??

Comment: Just added the result code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // Create the dropdown base
$("<select />").appendTo(".mob-subpages");
var opt = "";
$(".wrapper").children('li').each(function(){

    if($(this).find('ul').length !== 0){
        opt += "<optgroup label="+"'"+$(this).children().html()+"'"+">";
        $(this).find('li').each(function(){
        opt += "<option>"+$(this).find('a').html()+"</option>";
         });
         opt += "</optgroup>";
    }else{
        opt += "<option>"+$(this).children().html()+"</option>";
    }
    console.log($(this).find('ul').length !== 0)


});
console.log(opt)
$(".mob-subpages select").append(opt)
```

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0wp0ypng/5/)

This code works fine!!

Check and confirm

Comment: Raj, thanks for the fast response! It kind of works but seems to need some help. Here's the result I got from the code:


<select><optgroup label="Section" 1="">Section 1&gt;</optgroup><optgroup label="Section" 2="">Section 2&gt;<option>Section 2.1</option><option>Section 2.2</option><option>Section 2.3</option></optgroup><optgroup label="Section" 3="">Section 3&gt;</optgroup><optgroup label="Section" 2.1="">Section 2.1&gt;</optgroup><optgroup label="Section" 2.2="">Section 2.2&gt;</optgroup><optgroup label="Section" 2.3="">Section 2.3&gt;</optgroup></select>

Comment: Hey I updated the fiddle, <option>Section 1</option><optgroup label='Section 2'><option>Section 2.1</option><option>Section 2.2</option><option>Section 2.3</option></optgroup><option>Section 3</option>. This the one you want right